# C# 6 in Visual Studio 2015 - langversion 'experimental' is not supported

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

The following blog post on MSDN says that we have to set the langversion to 'experimental' to get C# 6 to work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp-now-available.aspx

However when using Visual Studio 2015 I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid option 'experimental'.

Is this a bug?

Comment: VS 2015 is not officially out yet, so there's always the chance that things are changing around a little. I suggest you add the `ctp` tag to your question, to avoid confusion for future readers (when VS 2015 *will* be out).

Comment: Btw. last time I played around with the VS 2015 pre-release, there was no need to turn on any experimental switch; the newest, experimental language features worked right out of the (proverbial) box.

Comment: The beta releases are coming fast and furious, anything you read is outdated in a hurry.  Basic conclusion to draw is that you now have a CTP version that isn't "experimental" anymore.

Comment: And a third note, contrary to what you're saying, the post that you're linking to is *not* from MSDN, but from some other blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 comes with C# 6.0. You don't need any extra settings, that was true in older versions.

You should also note that Parameterless Struct Constructors [didn't make it to C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1029).

This can be seen with [a TryRoslyn example](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGFAJ2FORgAUB7SZbAb2xi5n2LJhYwAHjm49CJcoISjO3XpIbMIyABQBKOVw5ixyABZgQAOiEwAvDAAMo3VwNHjCC9dtcAvpy3i+5Ji1VBIQAaARUYBE0xHTsYBxMzSxFvPUMTZ0sZb093IAA==) (which operates on the latest version of Roslyn).

This struct:

```
public struct Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Gives this warning:

> Error CS0568: Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors

Comment: I've tried using the ?. safe navigation operator. The compiler doesn't seem to recognize it as well.

Comment: @IlyaSuzdalnitski what version do you have? Which CTP?

Comment: Visual C# 2015 Preview; VS 14.0.22310.1 DP

Comment: According to VS 2015 preview features https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-preview-vs#ManLang C# 6.0 should be supported in the full version... I also have VS 2013 installed, maybe it's conflicting in some way.

Comment: It turned out, that I got syntax for the safe navigation operator all wrong! I was using str ?. str.Length instead of str ?. Length.